# Set Apache Alias for specific ServerAlias

Tags: apache-2.2, alias, serveralias

Currently, I have a VirtualHost defined like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias otherdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I make an Alias that only affects the `otherdomain.com` domain:

```
Alias /sub /var/www/other
```

So that:

```
http://otherdomain.com/sub -> /var/www/other
http://mydomain.com/sub -> /var/www/project/sub
```

The VirtualHost in question is not that simple in reality, so I'd rather not make separate VirtualHosts just for this. Are there any conditional expressions or similar that I can use inside the VirtualHost? Something along the lines of:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <If ServerName=otherdomain.com>
        Alias /sub /var/www/other
    </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your configuration needs are?  From what you've provided, it seems like a poster child for separate vhosts.. but what you're looking for can probably be done with mod_rewrite and a single vhost if needed.

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot use an alias in a If.

```
If "%{HTTP_HOST}
```

is not compatible with Alias, using it will result with Apache not starting and outputting the error message:

```
Alias not allowed here
```

You should create another VirtualHost with the corresponding name and configured with your alias.

Comment: Spent several hours googling and trying out before finding this comment. It should be more visible! Can you point to somewhere in the Apache docs where this is mentioned, because I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant bits of the Apache documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if

and

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html

In that case, something like this should work:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
    Alias /sub /var/www/other
</If>
```

I believe you will need Apache 2.2 or greater for the "If" functionality.

Comment: You're going to need at least Apache 2.4 to use that directive.

Comment: This gives me a Alias not allowed here

Comment: Can the OP perhaps clarify whether this actually works?

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found a way around.

```
<Directory /var/www/other>
  Require all denied
  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'>
    Require all granted
  </If>
</Directory>
Alias /sub /var/www/other
```

`<If>` + Require in .htaccess file inside /var/www/other should work too.